# Excel: Conditional formatting if cell is not equal to one of multiple values

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using Excel, I would like to conditionally highlight a cell, if the value of the cell itself is not one of several values.

The cell should be contain of the following percentages – 0%, 6%, 12% - or else it should be conditionally formatted to a red background.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471741/conditional-formatting-if-a-cell-does-not-equal-one-of-three-values), I would've thought that the below formula would work – but for some reason it doesn't.

```
=NOT(OR(D3=0, D3=0.06, D3=0.12))
```

`D3` is the cell I want to enter a value into, and it's the same cell I wish to be conditionally formatted.

I create a conditional formatting rule, via *New Rule* > *Style: Classic* > *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. I then paste the above formula into the formula/range selection field.

[image]

I get the error *There's a problem with this formula*:

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Excel 16.18 for Mac (from Office 365).

Comment: The formula does exactly what you describe in Excel 2013 on a PC. (complete shot in the dark: are you sure `,` and the delimiters you should be using? what happens if you use `;` instead?)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks! It works if I change the delimiter to `;`. It might be Mac thing, or a localization issue. This works: `=NOT(OR(D3=0; D3=0.06; D3=0.12))`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Select required Data Range and write this Formula as New Rule and apply an appropriate color.*

```
=NOT(OR(G142=0%, G142=6%, G142=12%))
```

**Note,** *adjust cell reference in the Formula as 
  needed.*

Comment: Using `;` as delimiter worked for me: `=NOT(OR(D3=0; D3=0.06; D3=0.12))`, but it didn't work with `,` as delimiter in my non-US version of Excel for Mac.

Comment: @Winterflags,, it's because of regional setting difference,, which is quite obvious ☺ If you feel now you can accept it as answer.